# What's necessary to write in a CSV archive with Python using import CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to perform a search in DB (ODBC Connection), save the search into a variable and write this variable with other variables into a CSV. 
My problem is, when I write the variable in the search, the code write all variables in a single CSV field, but I need every example in one field.

I tried to put "%a", "%s" and put ";" into every variable, but that doesn't work.

Observe that when I remove variable "a" and just write ID, NUM, CON and VAL, the code writes correctly, putting everything in one field. This problem starts when I change the 'example0' in variable "a" to `str(result)`.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM tabelaDeTeste")
result = ''
for row in cursor.fetchall():
        result = row


a = str(result)
ID = 'example1'
NUM = 'example2'
CON = 'example3'
VAL = 'example4'


Result = [ID + ';' + NUM + ';' + CON + ';' + VAL + ';' + a]

with open('dje.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(Result)

csvFile.close()
```

If I write this in one field of CSV (1A):

```
example1;example2;example3;example4;(1, )
```

This is expected:

```
example1 (in 1A) example2 (in 1B) example3 (in 1C)  example4 (in 1D) and (1, ) (in 1E)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Result = [ID + ';' + NUM + ';' + CON + ';' + VAL + ';' + a]` to:

```
result = [ID, NUM, CON, VAL, a]
```

and change

```
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerow(Result)
```

to:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=';')
writer.writerow(result)
```

Comment: Works, Thank you soo much! I'm begginner and didn't know about this "delimiter". Now, I learned something today. :)